# counting unexpectedly increased by 2 in 2nd attempt, while i coded it to just increment by 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this jQuery code to generate words memory quiz. Everything is working fine except for the variable `nq`.
In the first attempt, the code simply generates 3 words. After the user has guessed the correct word, it goes on for another trial in which it generates 4 words.

However, in the third trial it unexpectedly generates 6 words instead of 5. I am unable to find the mistake. Can someone help?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 // var arr is used to store temporary words generated in quiz
 var arr=[];
 // var t is used to ask question and match result using arr array
 var t;
 // var nq is used to set number of question in each attempt. this variable not functioning right
 var nq=2;
 function arraysave(i,data){
     arr[i]=data;
 }
 function arrayclear(){
     arr=[];
 }
 function question(data){
     t = data;
 }
 function nqplus(){
     nq++;
 }
 function nqdef(){
     nq=2;
 }
 alert("Please leave a like if you like this game and comment your review if any");
 $("#startgame").click(function(){
 $("#firstpage").slideUp(1000);
 $("#secondpage").slideDown(1000);
 });
 $("#startgen").on('click',function(){
 // stored words here in variable strings
      var strings = ["apple","mango","peach","banana","orange","grapes","watermelon","tomato", "blackberry","blueberry", "chips", "bottle", "doubt", "class", "school", "country", "ocean", "foot", "hand", "hair", "mobile", "phone", "great", "sololearn", "love", "help", "sad", "bad", "good", "bottle", "neck", "laptop", "printer", "program", "relation", "ship", "true", "false", "query", "hate", "game", "guess", "name", "future", "present", "past", "city", "alone", "party"];
var count=-1;
$("#startgen").hide();
 //this function generate a word every second in quiz
var i = setInterval(function (){
count++;
var output = strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)];
    arraysave(count,output);
    $("#words").text((count+1)+"="+output);
    if(count==nq){clearInterval(i);
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#words").text("Now click Next");$("#next").show()}, 1000);

    }
},1000);
 });
 $("#nextfinal").on('click',function(){
     $("#secondpage").slideUp(1000);
     $("#thirdpage").slideDown(1000);
  //setting here variable t to ask question e.g. what word came at place 3
      var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nq+2));
      if(t<1){
          t=1;
      }
      if(t>(nq+1)){
          t=(nq+1);
      }
      question(t);
      $("#question").text("Which word came at place "+t);
      });
 //below function works when user submit his answer after filling a text box
      $("#submit").on('click',function(){
          var temp= $("#wordbox").val();
          if(temp==arr[(t-1)]){
              $("#thirdpage").slideUp(1000);
              $("#res").slideDown(1000);
              $(".result").text("you win");
              $("#nextlevel").on('click',function(){
                 nqplus();
                 arrayclear();
                 $("#res").slideUp(1000);
                 $("#secondpage").slideDown(1000);
                 $("#words").text("Focus Here");
                 $("#next").hide();
                 $("#startgen").show();
              });
          }
          else{
              $("#win").show();
               $(".result").text("you loose");
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle containing the working code.

Comment: yes of-course, also i am thinking about this thanks to suggest. @Dan PHilip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its this line:

```
 $("#nextlevel").on('click',function(){
```

You are applying the click event every time they click the submit button. You need to put that block outside of the submit block, since you don't want to keep reapplying the click event.

Comment: Yes you are right i fixed it please kindly will you please elaborate more why it happened.

Comment: @AnandBhatnagar the click events stack, so the first time you click submit, it runs the `.on('click'` code, so when you click `#nextlevel` it runs your function once. Then, you click submit again, and it adds your `.on('click'` a second time, so the next time you click `#nextlevel` it runs the function twice. the 3rd time you click submit, it adds it again, and so on